# Nginx Config Causing unsuccessful EB Deploys

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config

I've recently migrated from Java 8, and Amazon Linux 1 to 'Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.1'.

I've done some reading and understand that rather than using the .ebextensions, I now need my custom conf placed in a .platform folder, as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

I've made this change, and all I'm now getting is unsuccessful deployments, as soon as I rename or remove the .platform folder the application fires up with of course, the default config. I've attempted to override the default nginx configuration as per the documentation above as well, to no avail.

At this point I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, as in theory this should be a simple directory swap within my built .war file and away we go. When the deployments fail, I check the eb-engine log files as ElasticBeanstalk suggests but there is nothing with a recent time-stamp indicating a problem.

My file path when overriding the default nginx config is:

`\.platform\nginx\nginx.conf`

Originally, I simply had a conf file at:

`\.platform\nginx\conf.d\myconfig.conf`

The config im trying to add is:

`client_max_body_size  20M;`

Any help would be great.

-- UPDATE --

I've managed to deploy the .war succesfully with the config in:

`\.platform\nginx\conf.d\myconfig.conf`

However the max body size config is still not applied. I did SSH into the box and manually add my config, which worked fine after restarting Nginx. However I can't do that after every re-deploy

-- UPDATE 2--

I've found the issue, my file structure was wrong.

I had a structure of:

```
Root
- .platform
- WEB-INF
- META-INF
```

When I needed:

```
Root
- .platform
- my-app.jar
```

The maven task I was using to copy the .platform folder (previously working on AL1) no longer takes care of this properly.

Comment: have you checked the file /var/log/eb-engine.log to find out what is causing the error during the deployment ? Please show it for helping you.

Comment: Hi, I think I'm right in saying the eb-engine log downloaded VIA the bundle on EB won't give me what I want? As I've attempted that and the latest timestamp in that file is from the last successful deployment.

I did SSH onto the box and grab it from there, the only thing I could pick out was a mention of a procfile? But maybe I'm missing something. I'll grab it from the SSH and update my question.